# Circle : How to get all co-ordinate list of circle parimeter?

Tags: geometry, math-software, circles

I want to find all the co-ordinate of circle.

I know the radius of circle and considering center co-ordinate as `(0,0)`.

So Is there any equation for finding all the co-ordinate of circle?

Comment: You may find this post helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25691/how-to-sketch-the-curve-of-parametric-equations

Comment: { rSin(@), rCos(@) }, will give you the points lying on the circle, for @ in (0,2*pi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a circonference centered in $(0,0)$, knowing the radius $r$, is $x^2+y^2=r^2$, so the coordinates of the circle are all the points satisfying the above equation. A point inside the circle is a point for which: $x^2+y^2\le r^2$. In polar coordinates $(\rho,\phi)$, you have for the circonference, the equation: $\rho=r$ and all the points inside this circonference have the property: $\rho \le r$. In order to find all the coordinates on the circonference, you can use the equation: $y=\pm\sqrt{(r^2-x^2)}$.